# vb.net - Pass Object in Sub and still use OnSelectedChanged

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

In VB.NET, I have created a DropDownList, and when something from the list is selected, a "OnSelectedChanged" function needs to be performed.

The problem is, the sub for the OnSelectedChanged to use, has an object parameter (dropdownlist object) that is being passed through, which causes an error: "does not have a signature compatible with delegate".

I know that you can't pass an object in a sub that is called by "OnSelectedChanged", but how do I get around this? Because the sub NEEDS the object to be passed.

Here is the HTML of the dropdown that uses the OnSelectedChanged to call the sub:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlgrv" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true" 
         OnSelectedChanged ="GrvDDL2">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

And here is the "GrvDDL2" sub that need to be called by the OnSelectedChanged with the parameter being passed:

```
    Public Sub GrvDDL2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, objDdlGrv As DropDownList)

        Dim message As String = objDdlGrv.SelectedItem.Text & " - " & 
        objDdlGrv.SelectedItem.Value

     End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, you might be making you're on problem here.  I believe the sender parameter will be the source DropDownList.  You just need to cast it to the correct type.  Might also pay you inspect the EventArgs parameter, you might well find some useful properties in there

Comment: When you say "object", do you mean some different object then the current combo box (dropdown list), or are you just trying to use/get the combo box value? If yes, then see below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can't just try and "change" the event code stub - that will not work - it has to match the built in system parameters.

next up?

Don't confuse a .net desktop dropdown list with a asp.net one.

in desktop land? You can fill a dropdown with a "class", and in fact when you data bind the combo box (dropdown), then EACH row of the dropdown will be of TYPE = DataRow!!!!

This is NOT the case for asp.net (web) dropdowns. They ONLY can be filled with a type of ListItem.

So, that means this:

Assuming this cbo box markup - NOTE HOW we set both the "value" and "text" settings. it is important to set both (or make them same if one column).

So, just like desktop land, VERY common to have two columns, say a hotel PK id, and the text column. So, with that in mind? Then we have this:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            Height="30px" Width="167px" 
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            DataValueField="ID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Note how we set the two Columns, "id" (hidden), and "Hotel Name" (displayed)

But, we feed it some data - WITH MORE then 2 columns, like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL =
            "SELECT ID, HotelName, City from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName"

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, con)
            con.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

            DropDownList1.DataSource = rstData
            DropDownList1.DataBind()
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("", ""))

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

However, once we "bind" and "fill" the cbo, then we ONLY will ever get back a single type of "listItem".

So, our code to run when you select the cbo?

Well, lets add autopostback = true (so it triggers when we select)

so, we now have this:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            Height="30px" Width="167px" 
            DataTextField="City"
            DataValueField="ID"
            AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

And we then add the selected index here (double click in the SelectedIndexChanged area)

[image]

And our code is this:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Debug.Print("index = " & DropDownList1.SelectedIndex)
    Debug.Print("value (PK id) = " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)
    Debug.Print("Text (display value)  = " & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
    Debug.Print(ComboBox1.Text)

End Sub
```

Output:

```
index = 6
value (PK id) = 107
Text (display value)  = Calgary
```

So, you can "only" return a list-item from that cbo, and thus use SelectedItem for this purpose. The dropdown is NOT like desktop - and while a desktop cbo can be filled with a list of objects - not so with web based - it only ever really get filled with a "list" item, and thus each row of the cbo box really is a a list item, and not some object like the desktop version.

so, delete your current cbo selected index stub - and let VS create it for you.

Note, that if you do NOT use the property sheet to create the event, say if the cbo box is nested inside of a repeater, or you just add the event stub from using intel-sense in markup?

Ok, you do that this way:

[image]

So, when the cbo is nested in a grid etc? Or you use markup and intel-sense and CHOOSE the "create event" as above shows? Then you get this for the code stub:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Or if from the property sheet, it looks like this:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
```

Either one should work - but let the "builders" and the IDE do the stub creating for you (from property sheet - double click, or in markup let intel-sense pop up the create new event for you).

You note how asp.net did NOT wire up a "handles" when you create the event from markup, but it will still work just fine. And note that in BOTH cases, the signature of the event stub is still the same.